# Driver for Broadcom ADSL modem

Tags: c++, c, drivers

I am interested in writing a driver for my Broadcom NDIS ADSL modem.

Given that I have knowledge in C and C++, what tool are needed for this job?

Comment: Since drivers are OS specific it would be a good idea to tell what OS you're targeting

Answer (score 1):

I've never written a driver before, but I googled "writing drivers" and found this...

http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?article=20

... on writing Windows drivers and this...

http://www.freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/drivers_linux

... on writing Linux drivers.